# Centralize dbsession for multisite yii2 application

Tags: php, session, yii2

I have a Multisite Yii2 web app. It means single yii2 app installation can be used from multiple domains.

I want to use DBSession. But I want to use a centralized database table for storing sessions for all the sites. Will it Collide sessions from multiple domains? If yes then how can I prefix session ids with some unique domain id?

How can I ensure every session id is unique despite being generated from multiple domains?